# How to change value of extJS textfield component inside extJS panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm here with so easy question, but couldn't find it... anyway, below you can see the code. This is panel with items inside it.
What i want is to change value of textfield with name 'intIP', it's inside panel, which is inside panel.
How can i do that? I found info about forms (.getForm method, but panel doesn't have such)

Thanks a lot in advance

http://jobtask.h19.ru/ - panel

```
var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: title,
    renderTo: document.body,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'Details',
        name: 'detPanel',
        items: [{
            name: 'intIP',
            fieldLabel: 'internal IP',
            xtype: 'textfield',
            readOnly: true
        }],
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 7):

In ExtJS 4 you should be able to use `Ext.Container.query()` method, which when passed a correct selector will return array of children components that match the selector.

```
resultsPanel.query('textfield[name="intIP"]')[0].setValue('New value')
```

Details on how to create selectors are here: http://localhost/ext-4.0.2/docs/index.html#/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

---

In ExtJS3: Every `Ext.Container` has a `find()` method, which can be ginven a name of property (`name`,`xtype`,`itemId` etc) and a value (`'intP'`, `'textfield'`, `'fieldId'`). It will return an array of chlderen components (at any level of nesting) where property has the indicated value. If in your container only one field has a name `'intP'` then you can just use:

```
resultsPanel.find('name','intP')[0].setValue('New value')
```

---

In both ExtJS3 and ExtJS4 if you have more children components with same name, using additional unique property like `itemId` should help.

Comment: but panel object has no method .find

Comment: :( i think i'm doing smth totally wrong. if i insert this line after object creation resultsPanel.find('name','intIP')[0].setValue('New value'); then chrome console tells me that Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'find'. Stupid me, I know it must be very easy, such obvious action

Comment: Ah. So it's ExtJS 4 then (What I wrote is relevant to ExtJS 3).

Comment: oh yeah it's extJS, sorry i didn't mentioned

Comment: and updated it once again, because `child()` will only return direct children components.

Comment: OMG, thank you! resultsPanel.child('panel[name="detPanel"]').child('textfield[name="intIP"]').setValue('New value') works as it should work! I wonder if I need to select EVERY child with .child or extJS is able to serach like jquery with .closest?  hey :) you answered this before i asked, you are the god, double thank you!

Comment: Am actually a human being but with godlike powers :P Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Specify an `itemId` for the textbox and use `resultsPanel.getComponent('itemId').setValue('Value')`

Here `itemId` will be limited to the scope of the panel, as opposed to `id` which can be used globally

You can also use
`resultsPanel.query('#itemId')` or `resultsPanel.down('#itemId')`

Check the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-getComponent) which works for you best

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put input fields into the panel then consider using Ext.form.Panel. Form panel has methods to find its input components like findField .